# Java For-each loop data type mismatch

Tags: java, types, foreach

I was converting a bunch of ordinary for loops to for-each loops in my most recent project and ran into a paradoxical problem.

```
    imgMap = new int[rows][cols];

    for (int r=0; r<imgMap.length; r++) {
        rowArray = mapBR.readLine().split(",");
        for (int c=0; c<imgMap[r].length; c++) {
            imgMap[r][c] = Integer.parseInt(rowArray[c]);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(imgMap.length+", "+imgMap[0].length);

    // print array in rectangular form
    for (int[] r : imgMap) {
        for (int[] c : imgMap[r]) {
            System.out.print(" " + c[0]);
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

**imgMap** is a two-dimensional int array (`int[][]`) to hold a 'map'
**mapBR** is a BufferedReader of the external file that the 'map' is taken from
The first nested for loop set reads the file, the second nested for-each set writes it to the console to make sure that it is read correctly.

I couldn't see a way to make the first for loop set work as for-each loops so that is a sub-problem I would be delighted if someone could help me with as well.

Anyway, back to the main problem. when I (try to) compile this the compiler regurgitates an error saying that the `int[] c : imgMap[r]` line has incompatible types, but, and here's the catch, when I change it to `int c : imgMap[r]`, *it coughs up the same error!* As I can't see how it could be any other than one of those types I am flummoxed.

I hope I have provided enough information.

***IAmThePiGuy***

Comment: thanks everyone who answered so quickly, it still amazes me  the warmth of this online community. BTW, if someone could come up with a way to make the nested for set into a nested for-each set similarly I would be grateful.

Comment: All has been solved and happy compiler!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first loop, you need `c` to be an `int` so that you can access `rowArray[c]` - but this should work:

```
for (int[] row : imgMap) {
    String[] rowArray = mapBR.readLine().split(",");
    for (int c = 0; c < row.length; c++) {
        row[c] = Integer.parseInt(rowArray[c]);            
    }
}
```

In the second loop, you just need to iterate through `r`, not through `imgMap[r]`:

```
for (int[] row : imgMap) {
    for (int value : row) {
        System.out.print(" " + value);
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Basically, you need to think carefully about the types involved - whether a variable represents an *index* into an array, or the array itself.

Comment: Wow... I warranted an answer by THE Jon Skeet! Thanks, that's EXACTLY what I wanted.

Answer (score 4):

you're trying to use r, which is an `int []`, as just `int`. It is wrong. fix it to

```
for (int c : r) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int[] c : imgMap[r]
```

as index of array it takes `int` and you have supplied `int[]`

It should be

```
   for (int[] r : imgMap) {
        for (int c : r) {
            System.out.print(" " + c);
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how it works:

```
for (int[] row : imgMap) {
  for (int cell : row) {
    System.out.print(" " + cell);
  }
  System.out.println("");
}
```

The outer for loop provides all rows from the matrix, the inner for loops all cells from a row.

Answer (score 3):

```
for (int[] r : imgMap) {
    for (int c : r) {
        System.out.print(" " + c);
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If i understand this correct it has to be like this:

```
for (int[] r : imgMap) {
        for (int c : r) {
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to code

```
for (int c : r)
```